# Custom validator to validate form field and model in Master-Detail - Angular

Tags: angular, validation, observable, reactive, master-detail

I have a reactive form that represents the "Detail" part of a item in the list. I can display the detail when I select an item in the list. They are bound by a service for passing the data so when a change in made in the detail, it is reflected on the list. e.g. "Name".

Item has a field for percentage that a user can change in the detail component. I would like to validate that all items add up to 100%.

I have created a custom validator using Factory function so that I can pass the array object of all the items. When a percentage is changed, I would like to validate against the sum of the field.

Validation is working but the issue is that when I do the sum, it uses the old value of the field rather than the new changed value using the foreach function on the passed array object.

Is there a way to make this validation work? Currently, for example when there are two items and I change one item percentage to 49% from 50%, it validates and no error shown as it is using the existing 50% and the sum is 100%. Then, I change the percentage back to 50 - And the error shows because it is using 49%+50% that is not equal to 100.

I tried to put the validation login in Value change subscription but validator is called before the value change function hence leaving me with the old value again.

Any help or pointers is appreciated. Thanks.

My validation function looks like this - I do not use the control value as the item value should have been updated in the collection.

```
static TotalPercent(collection:MyCollection): ValidatorFn {
    return (c: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } | null => {

      var currentCollectionPercent = 0;
      var isTotal: Boolean;
  
      collection.Items.forEach(item => {
        currentCollectionPercent = currentCollectionPercent + item.Percent;
      });
  
      isTotal = (currentCollectionPercent == 100) ? true : false;
  
      if(isTotal===false){
        return{'NotHundred':true};
      }
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you post your validation function?

Comment: I'd recommend, cleaning the value of the field in collection when you're focusing on the field.

Comment: If I clean the value of the field in the collection when the control gets focus but a user does not change the value, I will lose the old value as well. Won't I?